# How to use UniqueContraints on List<Items>?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

My entity looks as

```
@Entity

    @Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"id", "service_version_id"}))
    public class MarketVersion extends AbstractVersion<MarketVersion> {

        @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private Market market;

        @OneToOne
        private MarketVersion parentVersion;

        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
        @JoinColumn(name = "services_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
        private List<ServiceVersion> services;
}
```

and services looks like

```
public class ServiceVersion extends AbstractVersion<ServiceVersion> {

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Service service;
    @OneToOne
    private ServiceVersion parentVersion;
    @Column
    private String description;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ServiceImplementations implementation;
}
```

When I run this, I see

```
[hibernatetool] javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: market] Unable to configure EntityManagerFactory
[hibernatetool] org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to create unique key constraint (id, service_version_id) on table MarketVersion: service_version_id not found
```

I am sure being new to this, I am not doing something right, but not able to understand, what
Please advise

I want to have a new table which has constraints on unique(market_version_id and service_version_id)

Comment: Do you have a `service_version_id` column in your database ?

Comment: nope, how do I create one?

Comment: I think You put this constraint on the wrong entity, or are incorrectly using a OneToMany in MarketVersion when it should be a OneToOne type.  That is, assuming you want a service_id field in the MarketVersion table to be a foreign key to ServiceVersion and be part of the unique constraint.  You haven't shown an ID mapping for the entities - presumably the id field will be the pk and so automatically be unique without having to add a constraint

Answer (score 0):

The column in your contraint is named `service_version_id` while your join column in your entity you join on column `services_id`. 
Either you need to create your column `service_version_id` in database or to rename your constraint column to `services_id` depending on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I think all I need to have is unique on (id and services), how can I do that?